# What is the maximum RPM of a 1hp water pump motor?

Tags: motor

What is the maximum RPM of a 1hp water pump motor?

Comment: Nope.  That depends on the pump then matching the motor with pulleys to the pump

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a pump induction motor that runs on AC power? These run at a fixed RPM based on the line frequency. For a single-phase 1HP motor on 60Hz this is typically 3600 RPM; 50Hz will be 3000 RPM. The loaded RPM will be slightly lower due to ‘slip’.

Answer (score 1):

RPM in many water pumps usually using AC asynchronous or people like say it squirrel cage motor is depending on the motor frequency input voltage and the motor pole.

In the synchronous motor, the rotor speed is proportional to the speed of the magnetic field on the stator, but in an asynchronous AC motor rotor rotates at a speed less than the synchronous speed (have 'slip', and the speed will decrease proportionally with the load)

[image: Check here the table of Synch Speed]

[From: Engineeringtoolbox.com](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/synchronous-full-load-speed-induction-motors-d_1448.html)

The biggest market for the water pump in Asia usually using an AC motor rated at 220V 4poles with 50hz frequency so the speed is 1500RPM (no load) with asynchronous speed is around 1400RPM no load.

If you are unsure how much the speed, pole, frequency, there is usually a label attached on the pump, or if there is only model number and brand, go search on the internet your brand and model number.